# Передать в action данные из адресной строки

Tags: html, http, get, action, html-form

Допустим, мы находимся на странице (неважно какой) и у нас в адресной строке что-то вроде: `https://site.com/app/backend.php?param1=abc&param2=cde`

На странице есть форма с `<input name='param3'>` отправив которую вы должны попасть на эту же страницу, с первыми двумя параметрами + к ним должен приклеится третий. Т.е. в конечном итоге после отправки формы мы должны попасть на `https://site.com/app/backend.php?param1=abc&param2=cde&param3=aaa`

Мое решение:

```
<? $repeatRequest = http_build_query($_GET); ?>
<form class="form-inline" action="backend.php?<?=$repeatRequest?>" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Страница: </label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="param3" class="form-control" size="2" value="<?=$_GET['offset']/20?>">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">перейти</button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Но в конечном итоге мы попадаем на `https://site.com/app/backend.php?param3=aaa`

В чем беда и как это фиксить?

Comment: Из формы идет запрос на адрес https://site.com/app/backend.php?param3=aaa, а не на адрес https://site.com/app/backend.php?param1=abc&param2=cde&param3=aaa. Оттого все дело.

Comment: @labris не совсем понял. Как это избежать и сделать так, как мне нужно?

Comment: В action из формы должен передаваться текущий адрес страницы + param3=aaa.

Comment: @labris я понимаю. Но как бы я не пробовал, не получается. Можно код?

Comment: Сложно сказать, как у вас формируется весь URL, просто попробуйте его определить и также передавать в форме, например через $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] или $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].

Comment: @labris оба варианта не сработали. Первый привел на на нужную страницу, но только с одним параметром, остальные скинул. Второй вариант почему-то минует скрипт, выкидывает на 404, а если указывать явно скрипт, то результат как в первом варианте. Какие еще способы решения проблемы существуют, не подскажите?

Comment: А вот этот адрес у вас как формируется? - backend.php?param1=abc&param2=cde - откуда он берется, ведь тоже из запроса?

Comment: @labris есть главная страница, на ней есть форма. Заполняя ее, пользователь попадает на выдачу результатов (в адресной строке появляется backend.php?param1=abc&param2=cde. На странице выдачи есть доп. параметр, устанавливая который пользователь должен попасть на https://site.com/app/backend.php?param1=abc&param2=cde&param3=aaa. Проблема-то в том, что набор изначальных параметров в адресной строке может быть различным, но доп параметр (param3) одинаковый для всех.

Comment: А значение из первой формы - его можно сохранить в переменную?

Comment: @labris запилить костыль на js оказалось проще..

Comment: Тоже вариант (в вопросе его не было, так что я его не рассматривал). Вы бы привели ответ на свой вопрос в ответе, наверняка кому-то пригодится.

Comment: @labris сделано

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал выше, запилить костыль на JS оказалось проще. Есть input с button

```
<input id="page-number" type="text">
<button onclick="paginationManager()" type="button">перейти</button>
```

Когда юзверь меняет что-то в input и жмет на кнопку, то выполняется следующий скрипт:

```
function paginationManager(){
    /*Получаем содержимое адресной строки*/
    var location =  window.location.toString();
    /*Получаем значение, которое ввел пользователь*/
    var page = document.getElementById("page-number").value;
    /*Тут будет ссылка, по которой нас перенаправит*/
    var link;

    /*Если параметр page-number (тот самый доп параметр) уже есть, то изменяем его (\d) означает цифру. Иначе к текущим параметрам "клеим" дополнительный */
    /*Это нужно, чтобы избегать повторений в адресной строке але &page-number=3&page-number=5*/
    if (location.search(/page-number=\d*/) != -1) {
        location = location.replace(/page-number=\d/, "page-number=" + page);
        link = location;
    } else {
        link = location + "&page-number=" + page;
    }
    /*Переадресация на сформированную ссылку*/
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

Минус очевиден - отключен js - работать не будет. Буду рад увидеть здесь нормальное решение.